# Which Model to use when trying to forecast a Time Series

Tags: time-series, forecasting, arima

At the beginning I was already confident about using ARIMA (because it was the plebiscited and recommended one when dealing with univariate time series which is not stationary. (I thought I will have to deal with a completely non stationary time series data) So my concern is about the fact that my time series is being stationary just after the first two months (see picture) [image: plotted data] 
Should I still use ARIMA (or ARMA without differencing) or another method? Which one will be the "best" model for me to use regarding the Plotted data. 
Thanks

Comment: Do you have more background info about the time series? What happened around 2019-01 and 2019-02? Do you have other related variables available?

Comment: Yes sure. The values  of the observed variable sinks drastically in some interval of time during that period and became "normal"  at the middle of February. I hope its what you meant!

Comment: Yes, I can see that from the graph, but any intuitive explanation for it, any specific events that took place during these periods? If so, you could try capturing them with dummy variables. Are you mainly interested in predictive performance or inference?

Comment: predictive performance ... yes its during winter period ... its about energy consumption in a household.

Answer (score 1):

After looking your data, you can try **moving average** ,Simple Exponential Smoothing and prophet.

Comment: ok I will try them! Thanks. But how can you be "sure/confident" just by looking at the plot :).

Comment: Experience buddy!!!  haaa...    As you said your data looks stationary (doesn't have much trend and looks like mean is also constant).

Comment: For sure ... I used to make things being complicated. ok cool